# How can I verify App Indexing Implementation?

Tags: android, google-search-console, firebase-app-indexing, android-app-links

I've integrated the App Indexing as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing). In my implementation, I've just indexed public content like this:

```
 Indexable pageToIndex = new Indexable.Builder()
                .setName("some title")
                .setUrl("some url")
                .build();

 FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(pageToIndex);
```

and Logged user action as start and end like this:

```
 FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().start(getAction());

 FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().end(getAction());
```

My App Link implementation is tested & working fine, I can see the logs in Android Studio as well as explained [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/test#use-the-android-monitor)
But I can't see any links or results related to the app in google search (before or after app install) or able to verify public content indexing from [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/test#test-public-content-indexing) it always shows the same error.

[image]

But anyway I've released the app on play store and not sure how to check its performance and errors. 
I thought it would be shown in Google search console, but I can't see anything related to App in that dashboard.

If anyone faced something similar please suggest how to debug these problems.

Answer (score 1):

I found only one way to test App Indexing:

1. Turn debug mode for FirebaseUserActions

> adb shell setprop log.tag.FirebaseUserActions DEBUG

2. Find following strings in logs:

> ```
> 03-19 12:00:56.659 1536-12580/? D/FirebaseUserActions:   url: *your_url*
> 03-19 12:00:56.659 1536-12580/? D/FirebaseUserActions:   webUrl: *your_url*
> 03-19 12:00:56.659 1536-12580/? D/FirebaseUserActions:   pkg: *your_pkg*
> ```

And then you can see something like this in search results:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I can see the logs in the editor but can you see your app in google search?

Comment: Yes, I have added a screenshort

Comment: I don't know) It just started to work after some time, but it is worth to mention than we implemented deep links and links verification before.

Comment: Let's see if its works for me too #fingercrossed :P